# Dfsort weighted average

Tags: mainframe

Has anyone ever tried to do a weighted average with DFSORT or Icetool? If s0, I would appreciate an example, I have done standard min/max/average, but would like to manage a weighted mean on a final report

Comment: Wouldn't you give each item its weighted value, and then use that weighted value for the reporting? INREC with OVERLAY or BUILD, to extend the record with the weighted value (calculated with MUL or however you want).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. Might you have a working example?

Comment: If you have some sample data, expected output, and what you already use for your plain averages :-) Click on the edit link under your question to add the information.